# Calling protected constructor of base class from different package using super keyword

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor, package, super

How to call constructor of base class in one package which has protected access modifier from a derived in another package?
Like this:
Package that contains Derived class:

```
package MainPack;
import mypack.Checker;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Start
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        BeginCheck bc=new BeginCheck();
    }
}
class BeginCheck extends Checker
{   
     BeginCheck()
    {
        System.out.print("Enter a String to Check: ");
        super(new Scanner(System.in).nextLine()); //I want to call it like this
    }
}
```

Package that contains Base class:

```
package mypack;
public class Checker
{
    String s;
    protected Checker()
    {
    }
    protected Checker(String s)
    {
        s=this.s;
    }

}
```

Comment: That should work, with the only exception being that `super` must be called first in the `BeginChecker` constructor. The `protected` keyword gives all child classes access to their parent classes protected methods/variables.

Comment: Also note that the constructor is used to initialize an object. It's not the place to print text to the user.

Comment: @Pphoenix thanks, But i want to know why is it that super should be the first statement?

Comment: @M.S. When you create an object that inherits from another class, the parent class is created first. This is what java has decided, and there probably is a good reason for this (though I don't know which reason). Thus you only have one line to call the parent class constructor, since after the first constructor line the parent is created.

Comment: It's so that the parent Object is in always in a useable state before the subclass can begin initialization. This is so the subclass can't accidentally screw up initialization order and use something in the parent class that isn't ready yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First - you should not use a constructor to do I/O. It's bad form.

Here's an example of why the JLS requires a `super()` call to be the first statement in a subclass' constructor.

```
class Gradient {
    public final Color start;
    public final Color end;

    protected void blendTo(Color c1, Color c2, double BlendStart,
            double blendEnd) {
        // method to draw gradient blend
    }

    public Gradient(Color start, Color end) {
        if (start == null || end == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("No parameters can be null.");
        }

        this.start = start;
        this.end = end;

        blendTo(this.start, this.end, 0.0, 1.0);
    }
}

class ThreeGradient extends Gradient {
    public final Color middle;

    // This is invalid Java code
    public ThreeGradient(Color start, Color end, Color middle) {
        this.middle = middle;

        blendTo(this.start, this.middle, 0.0, 0.5); // If this were valid, it
                                                    // would attempt to use
        blendTo(this.middle, this.end, 0.5, 1.0);   // this.start and this.end
                                                    // before initialization.
        super(start, end);
    }
}
```

You can see that `ThreeGradient` depends upon data inside it's parent `Gradient`, as it should expect to be able to. If its parent `Gradient` is not initialized, it would not function properly. This is a hypothetical discussion, since it is not allowed in Java.

Answer (score 3):

```
BeginCheck()
{
    System.out.print("Enter a String to Check: ");
    super(new Scanner(System.in).nextLine()); //I want to call it like this
}
```

A call to the super constructor MUST be the first line in every constructor. Unless you are invoking the default constructor, then you can leave out the call and it will be inferred by the compiler.

```
BeginCheck() {
    super( new Scanner( System.in ).nextLine() );
}
```

You really should not be doing User IO within constructors though. It should be reserved for only initializing an object to a useable state.